# How to non-interactively enter confirmation

Tags: bash, module

Simple question, I have a bash script which installs some things.

At some point in this process, I need to clear the loaded modules with `module clear` however this requires a user input of `y`.

How can I make this progress without the need for user intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what is `yes` for

```
yes | module clear
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

For more complex situations, you can use "expect" scripting language.